# What is the regex expression or?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find all files that are named "abc", "qwe", "asd" or "zcx".

```
find . -name "abc"|"qwe"|"asd"|"zcx"
```

is this not correct?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
 find . -name "abc" -o -name "qwe" -o -name "asd" -o -name "zcx"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
find . -regex '.*/\(abc\|qwe\|asd\|zcx\)$'
```

---

Note: `-regex` will match entire path.